# Why did Judah's wife "תסף" Shelah?

Tags: hebrew, genesis, grammar

From [Genesis 38](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2038%3A1-5&version=KJV;WLC) (KJV, with interpolated Hebrew):

> 2 And Judah saw there a daughter of a certain Canaanite, whose name was Shuah; and he took her, and went in unto her.
>   3 And she conceived (**ותהר**), and bare a son; and he called his name Er.
>   4 And she conceived again (**ותהר עוד**), and bare a son; and she called his name Onan.
>   5 And she yet again conceived (**ותסף עוד**), and bare a son; and called his name Shelah: and he was at Chezib, when she bare him.

As you can see from the Hebrew (full selection not included due to poor bidirectional skills), verse 5 uses the word ותסף (to repeat?) instead of the word for conception, ותהר. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, Shua (Judah's wife) does not

> “תסף” Shelah

as this isn't a verb which takes an object. This verb (root *ysp*) is a [verb which means "add", or "continue"](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/414/mode/2up), often in the company of the adverb עוד "again" as quoted above.<sup>1</sup>

It is a fairly common Hebrew idiom (see [Gesenius-Kautzsch-Cowley §120d](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius'_Hebrew_Grammar/120._Verbal_Ideas_under_the_Government_of_a_Verb._Co-ordination_of_Complementary_Verbal_Ideas#GHGpar-120-d)) for continuing a sequence of repeated actions. As such, it implicitly "contains" the idea of the previous verbs in the sequence.<sup>2</sup> Here, of course, this implies a third conception, but without repeating the verb "to conceive" a third time.

This is, then, normal Hebrew diction. Rashi, for example, [takes no notice](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8233#v=5&showrashi=true). It can be classed among one of the typical [stylistic preferences](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MOoWBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA111#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Hebrew narrative art.

---

*Notes*

1. See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxSWM.jpg) to help locate reference to Gen 38:5 near the top of p. 415 in BDB.
2. See, for example, the comments of Esther Marie Menn, *[Judah and Tamar (Genesis 38) in Ancient Jewish Exegesis](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aKpKvKudargC&lpg=PR11&ots=7VgBMbCpRI&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (Brill, 1997), p. 17: "...the final verse implies conception as well" (see also fn. 9).